# Kendo UI + JavaScript beginner, confused by code

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

Hopefully you can help out newbie like me. I am currently using Kendo UI and the Telerik Appbuilder extension for Visual Studio 2015 to attempt to create a tablet app. My question is about the code I am seeing in both the tutorials and auto-generated code in the AppBuilder.

In the tutorials, many of the js files begin with the self-invoking function:

```
(function () {
  var app;
  //blah blah blah
}());
```

then in Visual Studio when creating a hybrid app, only app.js begins with this and the rest of the files says something like

```
viewName.app = kendo.observable({
 //blah blah blah
});
```

Why is this? How do I get these pieces to talk to each other and create more views with their own js files for the app? All the research I have done into JavaScript or KendoUI seems to be either too basic or too advanced to answer my question. Hopefully some real human interaction will help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, I understand your issue and this answer helps you. One major  point behind immediately-invoked function expressions (IIFEs) is to encapsulate variables so that you aren't polluting the global namespace. However, a problem presents itself when you have multiple IIFEs and you want them to either communicate with one another, or to extend functionality.

This seems like the case you're presenting here. In order to pass information between IIFEs, you've got to pass something as a parameter. It's much easier to show in code than explain, so, let's do that. I'll first illustrate code in your main app module and then a separate module's code which extends your app.

*app.js*

---

```
var myAppName = myAppName || {};  // our app namespace in global scope

(function(ns) {
  ns.app = {
    // blah blah blah
  };
})(myAppName);
```

*someViewModel.js*

---

```
var myAppName = myAppName || {};  // our app namespace reference

(function(ns) {
  ns.someViewModel = kendo.observable({
    // blah blah blah
  });
})(myAppName);
```

Note that it is not completely necessary to wrap the `someViewModel` code in an IIFE; however, you will need to rename `ns` to match `myAppName` and the loading order of your scripts must be controlled explicitly. Otherwise, `myAppName` will return `undefined`. With the IIFEs and variable check, loading order won't matter.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me! If you don't mind one more question, what exactly is this like doing?
    var myAppName = myAppName || {};
I'm happy to use code I don't understand but I'd like to know! Haha.

Comment: Since our script files load asynchronously (i.e. out-of-order), we cannot be 100% confident `app.js` loads before `someViewModel.js`. So, for each module, we have to check whether `myAppName` exists already. If it does, we don't want to overwrite it. If it doesn't, we want to be sure it is defined or else we'll get `undefined` errors. The `||` characters is an OR expression.